# What intuition do we have for a subalgebra of Lie to be abelian?

Tags: differential-topology, lie-algebras, riemannian-geometry

The motivation for my question comes from the definition of *rank* of a given globally symmetric space: it is based on the image of a maximal abelian subalgebra of a given algebra by the exponential map. I do not wish to enter in the details of this, since I want the answer to be more general as possible.

My question is: Is there a geometric interpretation for a subalgebra to be abelian? (Take the Lie algebra of a Lie group)

Comment: This is an aside to your question, but I believe rank is slightly more specific: you want a maximal *diagonalizable* abelian subalgebra. For instance, in the case of $\mathfrak{sl}(2n, \mathbb{R})$, consider the subalgebra of matricies which are zero except in their upper-right $n$ diagonals. This is abelian and has dimension $(n^2 + n)/2$, which is larger (for most $n$) than the rank you want $(2n-1)$. (It also doesn't behave like you want a nice Cartan subalgebra to behave.) (This might also suggest that this is too general a perspective for trying to understand rank geometrically.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lie algebra of a compact, connected Lie group $G$ is abelian if and only if $G$ is a torus (that is, if and only if $G\cong \mathbb{S}^1\times\cdots\times \mathbb{S}^1$ is a finite product of circle groups); to prove this, note that the exponential map is the universal cover. So, abelian Lie subalgebras of the Lie algebra of a Lie group give rise to embedded tori in the Lie group. A maximal abelian subalgebra gives rise to a maximal torus, which is quite crucial in the representation theory of compact Lie groups.

Hope this helps! Please let me know if you would like me to elaborate further.